# rspec testing with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, strong-parameters

RSpec test:
`get(my_controller_path, params: {})` is expected to produce params `{}` in `my_controller` request.

Instead if produces params `{ my_controller: {} }`

Is there a way to remove the controller name from the generated params?
Consider a use case of allowing query params without the controller name - `/my_controller?foo=bar`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `fetch`

```
def my_controller_params
   params.fetch(:my_controller, {}).permit(:atrribute)
end
```